# Access to Camera in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, camera, xamarin.forms, xlabs

I need to access the camera in with Xamarin Forms PCL. 
I couldn't find any sample that works.

I tried by installing [XLab](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Camera) and using its sample code but it has exceptions. For instance, with the XLabs sample I am using the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Takes the picture.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Take Picture Task.</returns>
internal async Task<MediaFile> TakePicture()
{
    Setup();

    ImageSource = null;

    return await _mediaPicker.TakePhotoAsync(new CameraMediaStorageOptions { DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front, MaxPixelDimension = 400 }).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsFaulted)
        {
            Status = t.Exception.InnerException.ToString();
        }
        else if (t.IsCanceled)
        {
            Status = "Canceled";
        }
        else
        {
            var mediaFile = t.Result;

            ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => mediaFile.Source);

            return mediaFile;
        }

        return null;
    }, _scheduler);
}

/// <summary>
/// Setups this instance.
/// </summary>
private void Setup()
{
    if (_mediaPicker != null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var device = Resolver.Resolve<IDevice>();

    ////RM: hack for working on windows phone? 
    _mediaPicker = DependencyService.Get<IMediaPicker>() ?? device.MediaPicker;
}
```

I get the following exception on `Resolver.Resolve<IDevice>():` `IResolver has not been set. Please set it by calling Resolver.SetResolver(resolver)`

How can I use this or other alternative to take picture with Xamarin.Forms? thanks for any tip in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add in your Droid Project, class MainActivity this code

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);
    #region Resolver Init
    SimpleContainer container = new SimpleContainer();
    container.Register<IDevice>(t => AndroidDevice.CurrentDevice);
    container.Register<IDisplay>(t => t.Resolve<IDevice>().Display);
    container.Register<INetwork>(t => t.Resolve<IDevice>().Network);

    Resolver.SetResolver(container.GetResolver());
    #endregion
    ....
}
```

and in IOS class AppDelegate this one:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    #region Resolver Init
    SimpleContainer container = new SimpleContainer();
    container.Register<IDevice>(t => AppleDevice.CurrentDevice);
    container.Register<IDisplay>(t => t.Resolve<IDevice>().Display);
    container.Register<INetwork>(t => t.Resolve<IDevice>().Network);

    Resolver.SetResolver(container.GetResolver());
    #endregion
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample code for xLabs Camera:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9paojg1q43ahnqk/XPA_PickMedia_XLabs_XFP.zip?dl=0
Found it from forum over here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/35636/a-sample-project-using-camera-control-mediapicker-of-xlabs

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly access native functionality in Xamarin.Forms. You have to user **Dependency Service** to access native functionality like accessing Camrera, audio etc.

Try this: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure IoC to get it working, and set the IoC provider to the Resolver with the Resolver.SetResolver method. Read more here, https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/IOC

Comment: Where should I do that? should I create this SimpleContainer on the PCL or in every dependency project?

Comment: You need to do that in every platform specific project.

Comment: Can you post sample code configuring the resolver in an Android project? I can't make it to work

Comment: XLabs has sample code, check the SetIoC method and especially line 103. https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/Samples/XLabs.Sample.Droid/MainActivity.cs